# Changing the control ID of a dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two dropdownlist which grabs data from a ViewData. The viewData holds a SelectedListItem, which is a set of times (1pm,2pm,3pm..)  the time doesn't really have anything to do with the model  (as I convert it to UTC) so that is why I created it as a viewbag.  I have it used in two spots in the view, but the code is producing the same IDs

```
@Html.DropDownList("times",null,new {@class="ddl"})

<select class="ddl" id="times" name="times"><option value="0">1PM</option>
```

I think it's relatively easy to change the ID, I just can't find the exact spot within the Html.DropDownList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the first parameter, that is what sets the ID

```
@Html.DropDownList("times1",null,new {@class="ddl"})

@Html.DropDownList("times2",null,new {@class="ddl"})
```

Comment: ah yes, for some reason I thought the first parameter called the viewbag id, I guess I will change that null

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, since it automatically picks the name from ViewBag, for cases where same list needs to be displayed multiple times, we may have to define multiple ViewBag properties all referring to the same back-end list data.